# Refer fragment in href or attribute for thymleaf template

Tags: thymeleaf

is it possible to use a fragment value inside an html attribute like href?

im trying something

```
<a th:href="~{text:test::text-login}">Tada</a>`
```

but url comes out like

```
<a href="<th:block th:fragment="text-login">LOGIN</th:block>">Tada</a>
```

Im expecting

```
<a href="LOGIN">Tada</a>
```

I tried out some other syntaxes but got same result

```
<a th:href="@{{logourl}(logourl=~{text:test::text-login})}">Eureka</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it to do exactly what you want by adding `/text()` to your fragment expression:

```
<a th:href="~{text:test::text-login/text()}">Tada</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works. I could not find this in the documentation.